# Batch File - Creating multiple users

Tags: file, batch-file

I am looking to create a batch file that will create multiple user accounts  on a local computer. I am looking for something of a prompt that will ask the user to input their user name, password, and their full name, then allow me to input another user after that one has been entered.

Any hints/tips?

Thanks

Comment: Questions describing your requirements and asking someone to write the code for you, explain how to write the code, or provide examples or references are off-topic. Please identify a specific problem or question about programming. Include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differ from the desired results, and the full text of any error messages you receive. Please read this advice on asking good questions: [[ask]], [[Writing the perfect question](http://goo.gl/1tBMnR)].

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but here is a simple solution for future readers to show how something like this can be done.

```
@echo off
:start
set /p username=Please Enter A UserName:
set /p password=Enter A Password:
echo ---------------------------------
echo UserName is now set to: %username% 
echo Password is now set to: %password%
echo ---------------------------------
echo If this is correct, press any key to continue. If not, please exit now!
net user %username% /add %password%
echo done
pause
goto start
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the first result that popped up when I searched for a Batch file. My requirement was also something similar but I had to read the usernames from a TXT file. So I modified @Petro's answer a bit to get mine working. I am adding my script below just in case anyone else comes here with the same requirement as me.

```
for /F %%A in (usernames.txt) do net user %%A /add Passw0rd
```

This will read the usernames from a text file called `usernames.txt` which has each username in a new line. Then it will create a new user for each line read, setting the password to "Passw0rd" for every user.